# tcsh multiline prompt/rprompt

Tags: prompt, tcsh

I know that this could look like something already asked before, but I cannot have those thing work for me, maybe because I use tcsh instead of zsh.

And there is no way for me to change shell, so if this is something "blocking" for what I would like to achieve, that's fine.

Basically what I have, right now is something like this:

```
set prompt='%B%~%b > '
set rprompt='[%{\033[36m%}%$VAR1%{\033[0m%}|%{\033[37m%}%$VAR2%{\033[0m%}] %P'
```

What I would like to have is a multiline `prompt`, with `rprompt` that is kept on the same line that the first line of `prompt` has, if that make sense.

If I just try to do something like this:

```
set prompt='%B%~%b\n > '
set rprompt='[%{\033[36m%}%$VAR1%{\033[0m%}|%{\033[37m%}%$VAR2%{\033[0m%}] %P'
```

(I've added the `\n` in front of the `>` symbol, on the `prompt`)

What happend is that the `rprompt` disappear completely.

There is a way to avoid this, or maybe use some kind of padding of some sort?

I've tried the r-padding bit, but looks like my `tcsh` terminal does not supports it or i'm using it wrong.

NB: If there is some other question with the answer that could help me solve this issue, please feel free to link me to that question.

Thanks

--

Edit:

This is what I would have:

```
PATH TO CURRENT FOLDER                                    RANDOM INFO + CURENT TIME
[if exist, my git branch] >
```

or, even better:

```
PATH TO CURRENT FOLDER                                    [GIT BRANCH] CURRENT TIME
RANDOM INFO                                                             RANDOM INFO
>
```

Hope that this makes clear what I would like to accomplish.

But, basically, I just want to know how to work with a multiline prompt in tcsh.

I am using tcsh version 6.17.0 running in gnome-terminal version 2.31.3.

Comment: Argh, sorry, my bad. I can reproduce this, the rprompt does indeed disappear when adding a `\n` to the prompt. I had a mistake when testing before, sorry.

Comment: No worries, that means that is just the way things works on tcsh ;)